# AngularJS ng-repeat display json

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to display the following JSON file in my Angularjs repeat.

for the following JSON results, I thought I could simply display the title in an ng-repeat with the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results">
    {{x.data[0].title}}
</div>
```

But I'm not seeing results.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Temp Title",
        "description": "Temp Description",
        "created_at": {
            "date": "2016-03-15 07:10:17.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "date": "2016-03-15 07:10:17.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "user": {
            "data": {
                "id": 29,
                "displayName": "chris.nakea",
                "email": "chris.nakea@freshconsulting.com",
                "join_date": 1458025279,
                "profile": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": 29,
                        "displayName": "chris.nakea",
                        "avatar": null,
                        "firstName": null,
                        "lastName": null,
                        "bio": null,
                        "city": null,
                        "zipcode": null,
                        "state": null,
                        "country": null,
                        "latitude": null,
                        "longitude": null,
                        "avatars": {
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "id": "default_avatar.png",
                                    "filename": "default_avatar.png",
                                    "url": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar.png",
                                    "created_at": {
                                        "date": "2016-03-15 00:00:00.000000",
                                        "timezone_type": 3,
                                        "timezone": "UTC"
                                    },
                                    "images": {
                                        "small": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar_small.png",
                                        "medium": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar_medium.png",
                                        "large": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar_large.png"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "coverPhotos": {
                            "data": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "category": {
            "data": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Staff / Events",
                "description": "Staff / Events",
                "colorCode": "#242156",
                "iconName": "icon-staff-events",
                "iconCharacterCode": "c108"
            }
        },
        "attachments": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "1d3f96e2286c27ee599c9e49a0c33da0",
                    "filename": "man.jpg",
                    "url": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/1d3f96e2286c27ee599c9e49a0c33da0",
                    "created_at": {
                        "date": "2016-03-15 07:10:17.000000",
                        "timezone_type": 3,
                        "timezone": "UTC"
                    },
                    "images": {
                        "small": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/50af58b3d52d8629e9f5c4d0dcdd5181",
                        "medium": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/51535d38f7b3cd82313eac2414059d83",
                        "large": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/a7be1dada18e4041cf48aea377cafa29"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Temp Title",
        "description": "Temp Description",
        "created_at": {
            "date": "2016-03-15 07:12:00.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "date": "2016-03-15 07:12:00.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "user": {
            "data": {
                "id": 29,
                "displayName": "chris.nakea",
                "email": "chris.nakea@freshconsulting.com",
                "join_date": 1458025279,
                "profile": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": 29,
                        "displayName": "chris.nakea",
                        "avatar": null,
                        "firstName": null,
                        "lastName": null,
                        "bio": null,
                        "city": null,
                        "zipcode": null,
                        "state": null,
                        "country": null,
                        "latitude": null,
                        "longitude": null,
                        "avatars": {
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "id": "default_avatar.png",
                                    "filename": "default_avatar.png",
                                    "url": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar.png",
                                    "created_at": {
                                        "date": "2016-03-15 00:00:00.000000",
                                        "timezone_type": 3,
                                        "timezone": "UTC"
                                    },
                                    "images": {
                                        "small": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar_small.png",
                                        "medium": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar_medium.png",
                                        "large": "https://cdn.band.dev/common/images/common/default_avatar_large.png"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "coverPhotos": {
                            "data": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "category": {
            "data": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Staff / Events",
                "description": "Staff / Events",
                "colorCode": "#242156",
                "iconName": "icon-staff-events",
                "iconCharacterCode": "c108"
            }
        },
        "attachments": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "a93cf8df7b60686e7ca6884d0ce353c8",
                    "filename": "man2.jpg",
                    "url": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/a93cf8df7b60686e7ca6884d0ce353c8",
                    "created_at": {
                        "date": "2016-03-15 07:12:00.000000",
                        "timezone_type": 3,
                        "timezone": "UTC"
                    },
                    "images": {
                        "small": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/cd04551395a355f4792fb85833156741",
                        "medium": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/4ff543cd8f5055bfecd703dedaee6d87",
                        "large": "https://api.band.dev/v1/file/5cdd9a0c3650228e0b93f9c6cd1404df"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Just remove the **.data[0]** and access it **results.data** in your ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the datap[0] part and get the output

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results.data">
    {{x.title}}
</div>
```

Output:

> Temp Title
>
> Temp Title

if you want to filter then you can do it by

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results.data | filter: { id: '1' }"> 
        {{x.title}}
</div>
```

Output:

> Temp Title

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.title}}</div>
```

And in your controller, bind the json to the scope.

```
$scope.data = jsonData.data;
```

Here's a fiddle for you - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anup1986/7pw4jceg/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results.data">
    {{x.title}}
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nvqf8oo7/6/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding. I finally figured out that the reason I wasn't seeing anything was because I am using ui.bootstrap's modal and I was out of scope.

I resolved this by moving the ng-repeat out of the modal, but I could have also tried to work with the modal scope itself.